# States not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm coding a sorting visualizer in ReactJS, and I use a state to hold the delay between each render.
When I change the slider of the delay, the sorting does not update.
I made it log the updated value, and in each loop I made it log the value **it** reads.
for some reason, when I read the `getDelay` inside the loop, and outside of it, they are different.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./SortingVisualizer.css";

class Bar {
    constructor(value, className) {
        this.value = value;
        this.className = className;
    }
}

const SortingVisualizer = () => {
    const [getArray, setArray] = useState([Bar]); //array to hold the bars
    const [getSlider, setSlider] = useState(50);
    const [getDelay, setDelay] = useState(2);
    //reset the array at the start
    useEffect(() => {
        resetArray(10);
    }, []);

    //function to reset the array
    const resetArray = () => {
        const array = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < getSlider; i++) {
            array.push(new Bar(randomInt(20, 800), "array-bar"));
        }
        setArray(array);
    };
    //a delay function. use like this: `await timer(time to wait)`
    const timer = delay => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    };

    //function to do buuble sort with given delay between each comparison
    const bubbleSort = async () => {
        let temp,
            array = Object.assign([], getArray); // defining a temporary variable, and a duplicate array the the bars array
        //looping from the array size to zero, in cycles
        for (let i = array.length; i > 0; i--) {
            //looping from the start of the section from the first loop to the end of it.
            for (let j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
                //changing the colors of the compared bares
                array[j].className = "array-bar compared-bar";
                array[j + 1].className = "array-bar compared-bar";
                if (getDelay > 0) await timer(getDelay / 2);
                setArray([...array]);
                //comparing and switching if needed
                if (array[j].value > array[j + 1].value) {
                    temp = array[j].value;
                    array[j].value = array[j + 1].value;
                    array[j + 1].value = temp;
                    setArray([...array]);
                }
                //updating the array and moving to the next pair
                if (getDelay > 0) await timer(getDelay / 2);
                array[j].className = "array-bar";
                array[j + 1].className = "array-bar";
                // Wait delay amount in ms before continuing, give browser time to render last update
            }
            array[i - 1].className = "array-bar completed-bar";
        }
        setArray([...array]);
        console.log("done.");
    };

    const combSort = async () => {
        let temp,
            swapped,
            array = Object.assign([], getArray); // defining a temporary variable, and a duplicate array the the bars array
        //looping from the array size to zero, in cycles
        for (let i = array.length; i > 0; i = Math.floor(i / 1.3)) {
            //looping from the start of the section from the first loop to the end of it.
            swapped = false;
            for (let j = 0; j < array.length - i; j++) {
                //changing the colors of the compared bares
                array[j].className = "array-bar compared-bar";
                array[j + i].className = "array-bar compared-bar";
                setArray([...array]);
                await timer(getDelay / 2);
                //comparing and switching if needed
                if (array[j].value > array[j + i].value) {
                    temp = array[j].value;
                    array[j].value = array[j + i].value;
                    array[j + i].value = temp;
                    setArray([...array]);
                    swapped = true;
                    await timer(getDelay / 2);
                }
                //updating the array and moving to the next pair
                array[j].className = "array-bar";
                array[j + i].className = "array-bar";
                // Wait delay amount in ms before continuing, give browser time to render last update
                console.log(getDelay);
            }
            //array[i - 1].className = "array-bar completed-bar";
            if (i === 1 && swapped) i = 2;
        }
        setArray([...array]);
    };

    const sliderUpdate = e => {
        setSlider(e.target.value);
        resetArray(getSlider);
    };
    const delayUpdate = e => {
        setDelay(e.target.value * 1);
        console.log(getDelay);
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="menu">
                <button onClick={() => resetArray()}>Geneate new array</button>
                <button onClick={() => bubbleSort()}>Do bubble sort</button>
                <button onClick={() => combSort()}>Do comb sort</button>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-container">
                <input
                    type="range"
                    min="3"
                    max="250"
                    value={getSlider}
                    class="slider"
                    id="sizeSlider"
                    onChange={sliderUpdate}
                />
                <input
                    type="range"
                    min="0"
                    max="1000"
                    value={getDelay}
                    class="slider"
                    id="delaySlider"
                    onChange={delayUpdate}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="array-container">
                {getArray.map((bar, i) => (
                    <div
                        className={getArray[i].className}
                        key={i}
                        style={{ height: `${bar.value * 0.1}vh` }}
                    ></div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
export default SortingVisualizer;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what the best solution is, but *a* solution would be to use [**`useRef`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

The problem is related to [Why am I seeing stale props or state inside my function?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) : On each render you are creating new functions for `bubbleSort` and `combSort`. Those functions use the value of `getDelay` *that existed at the moment those functions have been created*. When one of the buttons is clicked the "version" of the function of the last render will be executed, so the value of `getDelay` that existed then and there will be used.

Now, changing the slider will cause a rerender, and thus new versions of `bubbleSort` and `combSort` are created ... but those are not the versions that are currently running!

`useRef` solves that problem because instead of directly referring to the delay, we are referring to an object whose `current` property stores the delay. The object doesn't change, but the `current` property does and every time it's accessed we get the current value. I highly encourage you to read the documentation.

After your state variables, add

```
const delayRef = useRef(getDelay);
delayRef.current = getDelay
```

The second line keeps the ref in sync with the state.

Everywhere else where you reference `getDelay`, except `value` of the slider itself, use `delayRef.current` instead. For example:

```
if (delayRef.current > 0) await timer(delayRef.current / 2);
```

Demo (couldn't get it to work on SO): https://jsfiddle.net/wuf496on/

Comment: SO snippet does not support JS with async and everything newer. That is because a React snippet needs babel and SO has an old version of babel.